# Does this coding example from Microsoft demonstrate bad use of exceptions?

Tags: exception

From a tutorial demonstrating how to use unit tests for .NET:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx#bkmk_prepare_the_walkthrough

```
// method under test
public void Debit(double amount)
{
    if(amount > m_balance)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("amount");
    }
    if (amount < 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("amount");
    }
    m_balance += amount;
}
```

Now in the tutorial this code is there so we can write unit tests.

However, presumably, the business logic for this would be something like

```
try
    {
    account.Debit(amount);
    }
catch (ArguementOutOfRangeException e)
    {
    if (amount < 0) print ("Please enter enter a positive value");
    else print ("Insufficient funds"); 

    }
```

Now, I'd call this *business logic*. Am I right in thinking this is a bad example of using exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

In general, this *could* be considered bad since exceptions are supposed to be used for exceptional behavior, i.e. behavior that results in an invalid state. At first sight, it may seem that simply returning an error code or some object (e.g. `DebitStatus`) from `Debit()` may be better in this particular case, since the amount being out of range seems to be an expected situation where program flow can continue.

However, there's another side to it - throwing an exception **forces the caller to deal with it**. Error codes can be ignored much more easily than exceptions. So from this point of view, it's not necessarily bad design, and may in fact be good if `Debit()` would be a part of some public API, where you wouldn't want a developer to ignore such a condition. Some people might disagree though.

One way this could be improved further would be to derive two custom exception types, say `AmountNegativeException` and `InsufficientFundsException`, and then throw the appropriate one in `Debit()`:

```
if(amount > m_balance)
{
    throw new InsufficientFundsException("amount");
}
if (amount < 0)
{
    throw new AmountNegativeException("amount");
}
```

This way, the if statement in catch block can be omitted when calling the method.